# Installing Pocketsphinx/Sphinxbase in OSX for use in XCode 6

Tags: xcode, macos, openframeworks, pocketsphinx

I'm trying to use Pocketsphinx/Sphinxbase in an OSX OpenframeWorks application. I have cloned both

https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx
and
https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinxbase

And configured/installed them as per the instructions on the readme's. However I'm struggling on how to include them in XCode.

Has anyone attempted this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I removed pocketsphinx and sphinxbase and reinstalled them. Then I added the three libs as shown in the image below.

[image: Here is how I set the project up]

Also had to include 'Header Search Paths' to look for '/usr/local/include' and library search paths to look for '/usr/local/lib'

Seems to be working fine now.